# different keys goes into 1 file even if using Hadoop custom Partitioner

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

I am running out a minute issue.

I am trying to get different file for different keys from Reducer.

**Partitioner**

```
public class customPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, NullWritable> implements
Configurable {
private Configuration configuration;

@Override
public Configuration getConf() {
    return configuration;
}

public int getPartition(Text key, NullWritable value, int numPartitions) {
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % numPartitions;
}
}
```

And I set the following in my driver class

```
job0.setPartitionerClass(customPartitioner.class);
job0.setNumReduceTasks(5);
```

For reducer I have 5 keys

[3, 0, 5, 8, 12]

So I need to get 5 different files.

But once I run this code I am getting 5 part files but the results are not expected.

**OUTPUT**

```
Found 6 items
-rw-r--r--   3 sreeveni root          0 2015-12-09 11:44 /OUT/Part/OUT/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 sreeveni root          0 2015-12-09 11:44 /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 sreeveni root          4 2015-12-09 11:44 /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00001
-rw-r--r--   3 sreeveni root          0 2015-12-09 11:44 /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00002
-rw-r--r--   3 sreeveni root          4 2015-12-09 11:44 /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00003
-rw-r--r--   3 sreeveni root          3 2015-12-09 11:44 /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00004
```

In that 2 files are empty and the other contains

```
sreeveni@machine10:~$ hadoop fs -cat /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00001
3
8
sreeveni@machine10:~$ hadoop fs -cat /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00003
0
5
sreeveni@machine10:~$ hadoop fs -cat /OUT/Part/OUT/part-r-00004
12
```

Why 2 keys come under one file?

Am I doing any mistake in my code?
Please help

Answer (score 3):

Your partitioner is doing the right thing, so I'll try and explain why. Let's pass each of your inputs into your partition code and see what comes out. `numPartitions` is `5` as it's the number of reducers you set.

```
int hash = new Text("3").hashCode(); // = 82
hash % numPartitions; // = 2

hash = new Text("0").hashCode(); // = 79
hash % numPartitions; // = 4

hash = new Text("5").hashCode(); // = 84
hash % numPartitions; // = 4

hash = new Text("8").hashCode(); // = 87
hash % numPartitions; // = 2

hash = new Text("12").hashCode(); // = 2530
hash % numPartitions; // = 0
```

As we can see, we get the same results running it manually. Two keys come under one file because the partitioner assigns them to the same reducer. Partitioning will even out over the course of a larger data set, but you can't expect that code to automatically and evenly distribute all inputs.